# get URL parameter values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, url-parameters

I have created an application for getting the url parameter values using JavaScript, the application is working fine but the problem is that when the param key is having space then i am getting `undefined`

my code is as given below

**script**

```
function getParameter(paramName )
{
 paramName = paramName.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
 var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + paramName + "=([^&#]*)", 'i'), results = regex.exec(location.search);
 return results == null ? undefined : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

let say the url is like

```
http://localhost/myapp/index.html?User Id=145&Dept=HR
```

call

`getParameter('Dept')`  ===> Gives `HR`
`getParameter('User Id')`  ===> Gives `undefined`

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: Do you observe that you url http://localhost/myapp/index.html?User Id=145&Dept=HR actually is encoded into "http://localhost/myapp/index.html?User%20Id=145&Dept=HR" ??

Comment: so i need to call like `getParameter('User%20Id')`

Comment: in IE its not working

Comment: This is a FAQ and duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter

Comment: Also spaces are not normal in a parameter name

Comment: @mplungjan its not duplicate, here i am facing issues in getting param value whose param key is having space

Comment: @mplungjan actually its an external application url where url is having params like that

Comment: @AlexMan Then space should be encoded to `%20`